# C++ deleting local variables in function

Tags: c++, destructor

I have function that works on class A. Class A allocates some memory in constructor and frees it in destructor A::~A().

Now what if.

```
A someFunc()
{
//This is just to illustrate that it is possible for that variable to be overwritten few times before returning.

A locA;

for(some condition)
{
    //Something something
    A forA(i);
    //Something.
    if(end) locA = forAj;
}

return locA;
}
```

Is this good? Is destructor of that class called every time it created again in that for loop?

Comment: If you allocate some memory in the constructor of `A` and free it in the destructor, you definitely need to read about [the rule of three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29).

Comment: Yes, the variables have automatic storage so the destructor is called each time one of them goes out of scope. This is, provided your class is well behaved.

Comment: Yes the destructor is called every time, why wouldn't it?

Comment: @juanchopanza submit it as answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is destructor of that class called every time it created again in that for loop?

Yes, the variables have automatic storage so `A`'s destructor is called each time one of them goes out of scope.

Provided your class is well behaved, memory allocated in `A` should get dealt with appropriately. Note that this means that in your case, `A` should also have a suitable copy constructor and a copy assignment operator in order to be well behaved.

For more on that last point see [the rule of three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C++_programming%29).

Comment: Thanks. I have all. Allocation in constructor. Freeing it in destructor and proper copy constructor to treat it the way it should be treated.

Comment: @Hooch: Aren't you missing assignment? `locA = forAj` uses `operator=`

Comment: @MSalters It uses copy constructor.

Comment: @Hooch: It's not initialization (`A locA - forAj`), which does use only the copy ctor. This is regular assignment; for what other reason would there be an `operator=` ?